# ctags not recognizing node.js harmony generators

Tags: node.js, ctags, exuberant-ctags

If I have function like this

```
module.exports.login = function * () {
```

or

```
exports.login = function * (next) {
```

ctags is not able to index it.

Does anyone knows is there some workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to configure ctags to recognise these functions using a few custom [regular expressions](http://www.zeusedit.com/zforum/viewtopic.php?t=3367).

Answer (score 0):

Universal-ctags(https://ctags.io) can capture `login`.

```
[jet@localhost]~/var/ctags% cat foo.js         
module.exports.login = function * () {}
exports.login = function * (next) {}
[jet@localhost]~/var/ctags% ./ctags -o - foo.js
login   foo.js  /^exports.login = function * (next) {}$/;"  g   class:exports
login   foo.js  /^module.exports.login = function * () {}$/;"   g   class:module.exports
```